# Copy and paste visible cells only to variable row

Tags: excel, filter, copy, paste, vba

I am writing a VBA macro that copies a set of data,applies some filtering, then copies the filtered data to the next available row. My issue is with the last line "copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy GAR070...." which sometimes works and sometimes doesn't bringing up the error: Runtime error '1004': Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed.

If I then change the reference to the GAR070 sheet object to Sheets("GAR070") I end up with Runtime error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

As this sometimes works for me and sometimes doesn't I am wondering if it has anything to do with other workbooks I have open? Or something happening when I declare the objects?

There is a lot more to my code but I have not included it here, so you don't have to read through it all, but if you suspect there might be something going on there I am happy to comment it in.

I have looked previously on this site and others, for ways to do this, which is how I found with this method originally.

PLease let me know if I have missed anything and many thanks in advance :)

```
Sub Check_for_specials()
Dim GAR070 As Worksheet
Dim LRowred As Long
Dim filterRange As Range
Dim copyRange As Range
Dim newrow As Long
Dim wb as Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set GAR070 = wb.Sheets("GAR070")

'filter for "Y" in last column, copy this data and paste into the next available row

With GAR070

LRowred = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

' turn off any autofilters that are already set
.AutoFilterMode = False

' the range that we are auto-filtering (all columns)
Set filterRange = .Range("A1:O" & LRowred)

' the range we want to copy (only columns we want to copy)
Set copyRange = .Range("A2:N" & LRowred)

' filter range based on column O
filterRange.AutoFilter field:=15, Criteria1:="Y"

' copy the visible cells to our target range
newrow = LRowred + 1
copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy GAR070.Range(Cells(newrow, 1), Cells(newrow + 1, 14)) ' seems very volatile...

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit confusing, because you have

```
With GAR070
```

but no End With, so I can't tell where your With ends.

This may not be the source of the problem you're having, but this line:

```
copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy GAR070.Range(Cells(newrow, 1), Cells(newrow + 1, 14))
```

uses Cells without a qualifier.

If End With comes above this line and  Cells(newrow,1) refers to an address on the GAR070 worksheet, then it should read:

```
copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy GAR070.Range(GAR070.Cells(newrow, 1), GAR070.Cells(newrow + 1, 14))
```

If End With comes below this line, it should read

```
copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy .Range(.Cells(newrow, 1), .Cells(newrow + 1, 14))
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! It does work. And makes complete sense. SOrry for the delay in replying, I had to get back to work to test it out. It is much appreciated :)

Comment: I'm glad to help. Consider accepting my answer so that the question is flagged as Answered.